Pass alert from one script to another
I have alerts two indicators first over candles and second at lower pane. I want to pass the alert value Sell1 of first indicator to another (It can be either one from first to second or second to first ) so that I can create a new alert SellMix when Sell1 and Sell2 is true. Is it a possibility?
E.g: I want to create an alert BuyMix if Buy1 and Buy2 is true OR alert SellMix if Sell1 and Sell2 is true at same time via script.
My alert code is as follow:
//From Indicator 1
alertcondition(buy, title='Buy1', message='Buy1 Label!')
alertcondition(sell, title='Sell1', message='Sell1 Label!')

//From Indicator 2
alertcondition(MacNorm > MacNorm[1], title='Buy2', message='Buy2 Label!')
alertcondition(MacNorm < MacNorm[1], title='Sell2', message='Sell2 Label!')

I tried to set two alerts on each indicator, but given that one script returns Sell1 and other Buy2 at any time, it was not giving clear conclusion call and is not easily maintainable.

Two possiblities:

You would write the same code (except the plotting part) within the other indicator and use the alert variables directly.

You use a plot() for the alerts and in the other indicator, use input.source() to get that value.



Hi, Thanks for above answer, I have updated the question by adding my code, can you please help me now with code example, as being new I was unable to follow your above point#2.

If you have the source code of indicator #1, the best way to do this is the first way. For point #2, you might need to modify the first indicator.

I achieved the goal by point#1 thanks, I was also doing it earlier but chart was getting shrinked.
I would still try to learn how to do same by approach#2 for learning purpose in future. Thanks @vitruvius

For #2, you need to select the plot() of the indicator #1 as the source of input.source(). You can only do that manually via the inputs tab. Then later in code, you can check the value of this plot. In indicator #1, you can set the value of that plot to 1 for buy, -1 for sell and 0 for no action. Then in indicator #2, read that input and check its value (1, -1 or 0).
